# loadcontroller doesn't work on my http post

Tags: ionic-framework

Hello i have 2 toastmessages, one when the email is send and the other for when it fails. I was testing my webform but when i am pressing on the send button it has sometimes a delay before the message is shown. Now i want to use the loadcontroller when the user clicks on the button and disappear when the email is sent or failed to send.

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private toastController: ToastController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) { }

  sendMail(formData){
    this.simpleLoader();
    return this.http.post('https://portfolio500.herokuapp.com/sendmail', formData).subscribe({

      next: () => {
        this.dismissLoader();
        this.showToast('email succesvol verzonden');
    },
      error: () => {
        this.dismissLoader();
        this.showToast('email verzenden mislukt.');
    }
    });
    }

  async showToast(message: string){
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message,
      duration: 4000,
      buttons: [ {
        text: 'X',
        role: 'cancel'
      }]
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  simpleLoader() {
    this.loadingCtrl.create({
        message: 'email wordt verzonden'
    }).then((response) => {
        response.present();
    });
}

dismissLoader() {
  this.loadingCtrl.dismiss().then((response) => {
      console.log('Loader closed!', response);
  }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error occured : ', err);
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading ctrl is promise and Your http request is getting returned before your loading initialised.

Try this:

```
loading: any;

    async sendMail(formData) {
        await this.presentLoading();
        return this.http.post('https://portfolio500.herokuapp.com/sendmail', formData).subscribe({
    
          next: async() => {
            await this.stopLoading();
            this.showToast('email succesvol verzonden');
          },
          error: async() => {
            await this.stopLoading();
            this.showToast('email verzenden mislukt.');
          }
        });
      }

    async presentLoading(m = 'Please Wait') {
        this.loading = await this.loadingController.create({
          message: m,
          showBackdrop: true
        });
        await this.loading.present();
      }

    async stopLoading() {
        if (this.loading) {
          await this.loadingController.dismiss();
        } else {
          setTimeout(async () => {
            await this.loadingController.dismiss();
          }, 2000);
        }
      }
```